# Proving a quadrilateral can be inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

**Given triangle ABC with $\angle BAC=60°$ Suppose BP and CQ are are the angle bisectors, and $K$ is the incenter of the triangle. Prove that the quadrilateral $AQKP$ can be inscribed in a circle.**

I believe the goal of this problem is to prove that $\angle QKP = 120°$ so we have supplementary angles in the quadrilateral.  Having difficulty getting to that point.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$\angle ABC +\angle ACB = 180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=120^{\circ}$

$\angle QKP=\angle BKC=180^{\circ} - \frac 12 (\angle ABC +\angle ACB)=180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=120^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find $(\angle KBC +\angle KCB) $.

Comment: @Vlad: The asker asked for an insight. So I guess that an  insight should answer the question especially since the asker already knows that he has to prove that $\angle QKP$ is equal to 120 degrees.

Comment: I agree, however I believe that your response is more suited for the comment than for the answer format. If you would rather post answer than a comment, I would propose to elaborate reply. For example, write out explicitly which step of the solution is targeted by your hint, or how exactly  finding sum of two angles will help OP to get to the point (s)he is interested in. The way your answer is written now is a bit ambiguous (at least for me), as you do not specify whether you are trying to help with general prove, or specifically addressing one step which OP has problems with.